# Extracting URL's from mysql database and setting as single word clickable link

Tags: php, mysql, url, html-table

I would like to extract URL's from a mysql database. However I wish to link the URL to a single word 'CLICK' in a table.

The snippet of code below extracts data from a mysql database and puts it in a table as a series of rows. For each row there is a respective URL which I also wish to extract from the database. Instead of showing the full and long URL I just want to have the word CLICK against each row which people can then click to access that URL. Can any body tell me how that is done?

```
        $q="SELECT * FROM railstp WHERE DOWNLOAD='$changeday'";
                $r=mysqli_query($mysql_link,$q);

                if ($r)
                {
                echo "<strong>Network Rail Schedule (STP) updates downloaded: $changeday</strong>";
                echo "<p> </p>";
                echo "<Table id='customers'>
                <tr>
                <th>Headcode</th>
                <th>Traction</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>Departing</th>
                <th>Destination</th>
                <th>Depart</th>
                <th>Arrive</th>
                <th>ATOC</th>
                <th>Runs</th>
                <th>Load</th>
                <th>Speed</th>
                </tr>";

                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['HEADCODE']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['TRACTION']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['STARTDATE']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['ENDDATE']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['DEPART']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['ARRIVE']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['DEPARTTIME']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['ARRIVALTIME']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['ATOC']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['RUNS']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['LOAD']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['SPEED']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                }
                echo "</Table>";
                }
                else {echo '<p>'.mysqli_error($mysql_link).'</p>' ;}
                }
                show_records($mysql_link);
                mysqli_close($mysql_link);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your row code:

```
echo "<td><a href='".$row['URL']."'>CLICK</a></td>";
```

What this does is add the URL as the parameter to the link but as the link text only show CLICK. Replace URL with the column name for your url.

Comment: Just tried it out. Worked perfectly first time. Thanks again Vacation9 and Ironcito

Answer (score 2):

In its simplest form:

```
<a href="<?php echo $URL;?>">CLICK</a>
```

Comment: That about sums it up

Comment: Thanks Ironcito. Do I put this within the <td> </td> table area. Sorry pretty new to all of this

Comment: I don't know exactly how you want to do it. If the URL is a field in the database, then you could add a line like @Vacation9 said, changing the name of the field if necessary.